# Cast Enum values to string

Tags: c++, string

I know this is a simple question. But I want to cast enum value not red, blue but 0, 1, 2 etc to string. I want to see 0, 1, 2 as string. I am using c++ 14 compiler, any answer would be good.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    enum Color
    {
        red = 0,
        blue
    };

    Color color= Color::blue;

    std::string mystr = "I am super person my color enum value: ";
    mystr = mystr + color ;


    return 0;
}
```

Inother words I like to cast 0, 1, 2, as enum values to string. for concatenating with other strings

Comment: No. I want to print 0, 1, 2, 3, etc *not* the string as red blue.. My question so much more simple.

Comment: Do you want `std::to_string(static_cast<int>(color))`?

Comment: this is the only way? do I have to  use to_string? @Artyer

Comment: @MericOzcan side note: use std::cout instead of printf

Comment: What else do you want? With printf, you should do `std::printf("%d", static_cast<int>(color))`. With `std::cout`, you don't even need the cast (`std::cout << color` works fine)

Comment: I would ask why you want to do it ?

Comment: I know I can do it with std::cout. I want to cast it to string. I thought maybe a function directly cast it to string without extra int cast

Comment: No reason to use fprintf, that is C++, just go for std::cout << color;

Comment: In other words I like to cast 0, 1, 2, as enum values to string. for concatenating with other strings.

Comment: @MericOzcan if you need to use as string, you need to construct a string since an enum is an int. that's why you have to cast to std::string if you want that.

Comment: @MericOzcan your problem is exactly the same of "I want to write a string containing "1" inside" then

Comment: I canged the question then @Moia

Comment: @MericOzcan and the solution is still that from Artyer :D

Comment: so no direct cast I guess? @Moia

Answer (score 0):

An value of a plaint enum is just a `int`, so as pointed in the comments, it is the same of creating a `std::string` from `int`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    enum Color
    {
        red = 0,
        blue
    };

    Color color= Color::blue;

    std::string mystr = "I am super person my color enum value: ";
    mystr = mystr + std::to_string(color) ;

    std::cout << mystr;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your `enum` as color specifier and use its attribute as name your have to use different data structure which can store color specified number and its name. For that problem you can use `map` to store color number and its name like following
you can follow this URL to understand more about map
URL: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map

```
int main()
{
    enum Color
    {
        red = 0,
        blue
    };

    std::map<int, std::string> map;
    map[0] = "red";
    map[1] = "blue";
    map[2] = "orange";

    Color color = Color::blue;

    printf("%s\n", map[color].c_str());
    //or
    cout << map[color] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using a function like printf so std: cout might not be the answer here. Thank you for your help. I got my answer from the comments.

```
  #include <iostream>

int main()
{
    enum Color
    {
        red = 0,
        blue
    };

    Color color= Color::blue;

    std::string mystr = "I am super person my color enum value: ";
    mystr = mystr + std::to_string(static_cast<int>(color)) ;

    printf("%s", mystr);

    return 0;
}
```